# Asus 704a laptop monitor not on and PC is on and functional

Tags: display, asus-laptop

My ASUS laptop just got fixed and I have a 4GB RAM expansion added. The model is an ASUS r704a. It has as a factory default 4GB of RAM and an expansion slot for the new RAM I put in and somehow the monitor does not turn on but the PC itself is on and functional.

I hooked it up to my TV and I could see the desktop clearly. I tried to toggle it by messing with the magnetic sensor with a magnet. Fully reset it.  Power it on and off and right now I'm using that same computer on the TV screen typing this post.

Does anyone know or have any idea to why I cannot view my screen normally when the laptop is on?

Comment: Did you or the repair person unplug anything then forget to plug it back in?

Comment: No I worked after it was repaired just when after a few weeks later